# como crear suma independiente de un array anidado de 3 niveles

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Hola estimados estoy tratando de sumar los valores una array anidado con 3 niveles ya logre hacer el primer nivel pero el segundo nivel y tercer nivel se me ha hecho dificil
necesito hacer el reduce sum para el sector y rubro

necesito acular cada variable de cada nivel ya que esos valores lo tengo que mostrar en una tabla anidada
en este link les muestro lo que intendo hacer-->https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cc85fm

aca dejo el array de ejemplo

```
 DATA =[
  {
    "mercado": "AGROALIM",
    "sector": [
      {
        "sector": "AGRICOLA",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "FORRAJE",
            "v48": 0.65046,
            "a0": 0.63372546,
            "a1": 0.65046,
            "a2": 0.65046,
            "a3": 0,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0
          },
          {
            "rubro": "FRUTAS",
            "v48": 3.0869145,
            "a0": 0.34910247,
            "a1": 3.0869145,
            "a2": 3.0869145,
            "a3": 0.24792662,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0.09785357,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0.02057352,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0.06257278,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0.031674,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0.037379857,
            "vT01": 0.16207525,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0.06038016,
            "vT06": 0.025471216,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0.37955326
          },
          {
            "rubro": "UVAS",
            "v48": 2.3387132,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 2.3387132,
            "a2": 2.3387132,
            "a3": 0,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0
          },
          {
            "rubro": "VEGETALES",
            "v48": 54.80923,
            "a0": 25.5776,
            "a1": 54.80923,
            "a2": 54.80923,
            "a3": 6.0376153,
            "vT01A": 0.055398982,
            "vT02A": 0.11872213,
            "vT03A": 0.40296635,
            "vT04A": 0.6623712,
            "vT05A": 0.16378467,
            "vT06A": 0.5053909,
            "vT07A": 0.20850898,
            "vT08A": 0.4101349,
            "vT09A": 5.769443,
            "vT10A": 0.1709257,
            "vT11A": 0.0833456,
            "vT12A": 0.5841922,
            "vT01": 0.49883845,
            "vT02": 2.701045,
            "vT03": 0.4390471,
            "vT04": 0.8045832,
            "vT05": 0.7468361,
            "vT06": 0.7957134,
            "vT07": 0.051551737,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 13.212614
          }
        ],
        "v48": 60.88532,
        "a0": 26.560429,
        "a1": 60.88532,
        "a2": 60.88532,
        "a3": 6.2855415,
        "vT01A": 0.055398982,
        "vT02A": 0.11872213,
        "vT03A": 0.5008199,
        "vT04A": 0.6623712,
        "vT05A": 0.16378467,
        "vT06A": 0.52596444,
        "vT07A": 0.20850898,
        "vT08A": 0.4727077,
        "vT09A": 5.769443,
        "vT10A": 0.20259972,
        "vT11A": 0.0833456,
        "vT12A": 0.6215721,
        "vT01": 0.6609137,
        "vT02": 2.701045,
        "vT03": 0.4390471,
        "vT04": 0.8045832,
        "vT05": 0.8072163,
        "vT06": 0.82118464,
        "vT07": 0.051551737,
        "vT08": 0,
        "vT09": 0,
        "vT10": 0,
        "vT11": 0,
        "vT12": 0,
        "y": 13.592167
      },
      {
        "sector": "ALIMENTOS",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "BEBIDAS",
            "v48": 1.2313427,
            "a0": 0.16636576,
            "a1": 1.2313427,
            "a2": 1.2313427,
            "a3": 0.61833805,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0.028110642,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0.5902274,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0.61833805
          },
          {
            "rubro": "CECINAS",
            "v48": 12.669079,
            "a0": 7.1717906,
            "a1": 12.669079,
            "a2": 12.669079,
            "a3": 2.115978,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0.8826354,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0.83775246,
            "vT12A": 0.317056,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0.530576,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 1.1249005,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0.46050146,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 3.6929202
          },
          {
            "rubro": "CONSERVAS",
            "v48": 33.866325,
            "a0": 8.312485,
            "a1": 33.866325,
            "a2": 33.866325,
            "a3": 12.918893,
            "vT01A": 0.043527644,
            "vT02A": 0.05901425,
            "vT03A": 0.4822467,
            "vT04A": 1.2400141,
            "vT05A": 0.6903497,
            "vT06A": 0.072409354,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0.15224335,
            "vT09A": 2.918837,
            "vT10A": 0.22558174,
            "vT11A": 1.2857621,
            "vT12A": 0.20941176,
            "vT01": 0.5832114,
            "vT02": 0.24598771,
            "vT03": 0.3761826,
            "vT04": 0.24153748,
            "vT05": 11.142077,
            "vT06": 0.18108085,
            "vT07": 0.14881521,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 17.561913
          },
          {
            "rubro": "HARINA",
            "v48": 3.7472982,
            "a0": 0.011847539,
            "a1": 3.7472982,
            "a2": 3.7472982,
            "a3": 0,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 2.8003738,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 2.8003738
          },
          {
            "rubro": "LACTEOS",
            "v48": 5.181415,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 5.181415,
            "a2": 5.181415,
            "a3": 0,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0
          },
          {
            "rubro": "VINO",
            "v48": 6.591118,
            "a0": 4.3435507,
            "a1": 6.591118,
            "a2": 6.591118,
            "a3": 0,
            "vT01A": 1.6822232,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0
          }
        ],
        "v48": 63.28658,
        "a0": 20.006039,
        "a1": 63.28658,
        "a2": 63.28658,
        "a3": 15.653209,
        "vT01A": 1.7257509,
        "vT02A": 0.05901425,
        "vT03A": 0.4822467,
        "vT04A": 1.2400141,
        "vT05A": 0.6903497,
        "vT06A": 0.072409354,
        "vT07A": 0,
        "vT08A": 0.15224335,
        "vT09A": 6.601846,
        "vT10A": 0.22558174,
        "vT11A": 2.1235144,
        "vT12A": 0.52646774,
        "vT01": 0.5832114,
        "vT02": 0.8046744,
        "vT03": 0.3761826,
        "vT04": 0.24153748,
        "vT05": 12.266977,
        "vT06": 0.7713083,
        "vT07": 0.6093167,
        "vT08": 0,
        "vT09": 0,
        "vT10": 0,
        "vT11": 0,
        "vT12": 0,
        "y": 24.673546
      },
      {
        "sector": "ANIMALES",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "ANIMALES",
            "v48": 0,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 0,
            "a2": 0,
            "a3": 0,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0
          },
          {
            "rubro": "CRIANZA",
            "v48": 7.259204,
            "a0": 3.696346,
            "a1": 7.259204,
            "a2": 7.259204,
            "a3": 1.4296815,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0.25565538,
            "vT03A": 0.014355288,
            "vT04A": 0.00022871255,
            "vT05A": 0.016823303,
            "vT06A": 0.06453781,
            "vT07A": 0.11999396,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0.014509413,
            "vT11A": 0.81407684,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0.024524018,
            "vT02": 0.61989063,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0.10152385,
            "vT05": 0.041058905,
            "vT06": 0.64268416,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 2.3782618
          }
        ],
        "v48": 7.259204,
        "a0": 3.696346,
        "a1": 7.259204,
        "a2": 7.259204,
        "a3": 1.4296815,
        "vT01A": 0,
        "vT02A": 0.25565538,
        "vT03A": 0.014355288,
        "vT04A": 0.00022871255,
        "vT05A": 0.016823303,
        "vT06A": 0.06453781,
        "vT07A": 0.11999396,
        "vT08A": 0,
        "vT09A": 0,
        "vT10A": 0.014509413,
        "vT11A": 0.81407684,
        "vT12A": 0,
        "vT01": 0.024524018,
        "vT02": 0.61989063,
        "vT03": 0,
        "vT04": 0.10152385,
        "vT05": 0.041058905,
        "vT06": 0.64268416,
        "vT07": 0,
        "vT08": 0,
        "vT09": 0,
        "vT10": 0,
        "vT11": 0,
        "vT12": 0,
        "y": 2.3782618
      },
     
    ],
    "v48": 665.07355,
    "a0": 198.37775,
    "a1": 665.07355,
    "a2": 665.07355,
    "a3": 129.8242,
    "vT01A": 13.9066305,
    "vT02A": 23.493769,
    "vT03A": 7.6918764,
    "vT04A": 9.9504385,
    "vT05A": 28.584347,
    "vT06A": 12.52397,
    "vT07A": 13.321441,
    "vT08A": 7.7590566,
    "vT09A": 18.949095,
    "vT10A": 6.5043373,
    "vT11A": 11.27076,
    "vT12A": 8.31015,
    "vT01": 37.403843,
    "vT02": 21.79155,
    "vT03": 20.041506,
    "vT04": 9.63965,
    "vT05": 21.299023,
    "vT06": 11.182072,
    "vT07": 8.466562,
    "vT08": 0,
    "vT09": 0,
    "vT10": 0,
    "vT11": 0,
    "vT12": 0,
    "y": 187.47249
  },
  {
    "mercado": "COMERCIO",
    "sector": [
      {
        "sector": "DST MATERIALES",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "ACERO",
            "v48": 59.89149,
            "a0": 13.750453,
            "a1": 59.89149,
            "a2": 59.89149,
            "a3": 5.890896,
            "vT01A": 1.2521733,
            "vT02A": 0.9588881,
            "vT03A": 0.3330148,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0.18357044,
            "vT06A": 1.5366033,
            "vT07A": 2.8565886,
            "vT08A": 1.8769006,
            "vT09A": 1.0571475,
            "vT10A": 0.7054244,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0.052483056,
            "vT01": 2.1818054,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0.49541363,
            "vT05": 0.050943423,
            "vT06": 2.3908103,
            "vT07": 0.7719231,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 11.667517
          },
          {
            "rubro": "DST MATERIALES",
            "v48": 4.495523,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 4.495523,
            "a2": 4.495523,
            "a3": 4.104237,
            "vT01A": 0.108139955,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0.10088453,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0.1307,
            "vT11A": 0.05156168,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0.021255944,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0.85,
            "vT05": 1.632981,
            "vT06": 1.6,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 4.387383
          },
          {
            "rubro": "M CONSTRUCCION",
            "v48": 4410.735,
            "a0": 1214.6946,
            "a1": 4410.735,
            "a2": 4410.735,
            "a3": 519.7534,
            "vT01A": 88.204605,
            "vT02A": 85.186066,
            "vT03A": 101.98892,
            "vT04A": 81.91314,
            "vT05A": 250.5034,
            "vT06A": 67.29768,
            "vT07A": 133.73201,
            "vT08A": 70.70217,
            "vT09A": 75.05774,
            "vT10A": 90.81847,
            "vT11A": 108.72759,
            "vT12A": 80.19829,
            "vT01": 83.45438,
            "vT02": 89.62223,
            "vT03": 74.67438,
            "vT04": 86.20881,
            "vT05": 88.00498,
            "vT06": 59.36364,
            "vT07": 38.425026,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 1040.5647
          },
          {
            "rubro": "M ELECTRICO",
            "v48": 115.70385,
            "a0": 28.76517,
            "a1": 115.70385,
            "a2": 115.70385,
            "a3": 14.594371,
            "vT01A": 3.1988232,
            "vT02A": 1.7908764,
            "vT03A": 6.0568175,
            "vT04A": 1.6404878,
            "vT05A": 2.7894804,
            "vT06A": 0.6181293,
            "vT07A": 11.382304,
            "vT08A": 1.0435791,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0.04999324,
            "vT11A": 5.1678367,
            "vT12A": -0.15237466,
            "vT01": 8.625343,
            "vT02": 0.21113923,
            "vT03": 0.024106765,
            "vT04": 0.21929945,
            "vT05": 3.8756096,
            "vT06": 1.5990952,
            "vT07": 0.03977734,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 32.045933
          },
          {
            "rubro": "TORNILLOS",
            "v48": 16.949966,
            "a0": 13.514951,
            "a1": 16.949966,
            "a2": 16.949966,
            "a3": 0,
            "vT01A": 0.11012014,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": -9.700002e-9,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": -9.700002e-9
          }
        ],
        "v48": 4607.7754,
        "a0": 1270.7251,
        "a1": 4607.7754,
        "a2": 4607.7754,
        "a3": 544.34296,
        "vT01A": 92.873856,
        "vT02A": 87.93583,
        "vT03A": 108.37875,
        "vT04A": 83.55363,
        "vT05A": 253.47646,
        "vT06A": 69.452415,
        "vT07A": 148.07178,
        "vT08A": 73.62265,
        "vT09A": 76.11488,
        "vT10A": 91.70459,
        "vT11A": 113.94699,
        "vT12A": 80.0984,
        "vT01": 94.282776,
        "vT02": 89.833374,
        "vT03": 74.69849,
        "vT04": 87.77352,
        "vT05": 93.56452,
        "vT06": 64.953545,
        "vT07": 39.236725,
        "vT08": 0,
        "vT09": 0,
        "vT10": 0,
        "vT11": 0,
        "vT12": 0,
        "y": 1088.6655
      },
      {
        "sector": "DST UTILES",
        "rubro": [
          {
            "rubro": "U AUTOMOTRIZ",
            "v48": 553.1792,
            "a0": 114.20921,
            "a1": 553.1792,
            "a2": 553.1792,
            "a3": 143.01349,
            "vT01A": 30.673552,
            "vT02A": 9.388207,
            "vT03A": 17.597233,
            "vT04A": 4.239662,
            "vT05A": 1.0597823,
            "vT06A": 4.6842523,
            "vT07A": 10.862326,
            "vT08A": 84.404495,
            "vT09A": 14.852571,
            "vT10A": 8.198037,
            "vT11A": 16.700201,
            "vT12A": 26.559603,
            "vT01": 8.06888,
            "vT02": 11.899355,
            "vT03": 20.528994,
            "vT04": 44.981087,
            "vT05": 35.389843,
            "vT06": 14.330837,
            "vT07": 7.8144875,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 296.7762
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U MINERIA",
            "v48": 159.25165,
            "a0": 52.779083,
            "a1": 159.25165,
            "a2": 159.25165,
            "a3": 15.5641575,
            "vT01A": 2.959542,
            "vT02A": 1.448054,
            "vT03A": 2.529163,
            "vT04A": 2.2003427,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 5.288731,
            "vT07A": 5.2740483,
            "vT08A": 4.676426,
            "vT09A": 2.3642013,
            "vT10A": 2.663408,
            "vT11A": 1.7252575,
            "vT12A": 0.953735,
            "vT01": 5.6001625,
            "vT02": 1.4222362,
            "vT03": 1.373418,
            "vT04": 1.1474456,
            "vT05": 2.0500414,
            "vT06": 0.85551345,
            "vT07": 3.11534,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 30.105894
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U OFICINA",
            "v48": 1.7601775,
            "a0": 0.33449724,
            "a1": 1.7601775,
            "a2": 1.7601775,
            "a3": 0.12675817,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0.086706035,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0.03884596,
            "vT06A": 0.061421458,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0.031731896,
            "vT09A": 0.007384812,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0.064912856,
            "vT12A": 0.17284603,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0.076486185,
            "vT03": -3.9139942e-7,
            "vT04": 0.03040853,
            "vT05": 0.0067450376,
            "vT06": 0.013118812,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0.40363377
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U SALUD",
            "v48": 1.2493496,
            "a0": 1.2493496,
            "a1": 1.2493496,
            "a2": 1.2493496,
            "a3": 0,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U TALLER",
            "v48": 1033.7096,
            "a0": 202.98636,
            "a1": 1033.7096,
            "a2": 1033.7096,
            "a3": 251.42595,
            "vT01A": 6.4677057,
            "vT02A": 15.989225,
            "vT03A": 15.53408,
            "vT04A": 35.536625,
            "vT05A": 15.547237,
            "vT06A": 27.717808,
            "vT07A": 24.218449,
            "vT08A": 19.516333,
            "vT09A": 31.371515,
            "vT10A": 20.341627,
            "vT11A": 29.097357,
            "vT12A": 33.7945,
            "vT01": 39.48896,
            "vT02": 42.00159,
            "vT03": 26.439568,
            "vT04": 18.248316,
            "vT05": 24.07277,
            "vT06": 28.076014,
            "vT07": 73.09873,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 336.667
          },
          {
            "rubro": "U VESTIMENTA",
            "v48": 0.12437412,
            "a0": 0,
            "a1": 0.12437412,
            "a2": 0.12437412,
            "a3": 0,
            "vT01A": 0,
            "vT02A": 0,
            "vT03A": 0,
            "vT04A": 0,
            "vT05A": 0,
            "vT06A": 0,
            "vT07A": 0,
            "vT08A": 0,
            "vT09A": 0.12437412,
            "vT10A": 0,
            "vT11A": 0,
            "vT12A": 0,
            "vT01": 0,
            "vT02": 0,
            "vT03": 0,
            "vT04": 0,
            "vT05": 0,
            "vT06": 0,
            "vT07": 0,
            "vT08": 0,
            "vT09": 0,
            "vT10": 0,
            "vT11": 0,
            "vT12": 0,
            "y": 0.12437412
          }
        ],
        "v48": 1749.2743,
        "a0": 371.5585,
        "a1": 1749.2743,
        "a2": 1749.2743,
        "a3": 410.13034,
        "vT01A": 40.1008,
        "vT02A": 26.825487,
        "vT03A": 35.74718,
        "vT04A": 41.97663,
        "vT05A": 16.645866,
        "vT06A": 37.752213,
        "vT07A": 40.354824,
        "vT08A": 108.62898,
        "vT09A": 48.720047,
        "vT10A": 31.203074,
        "vT11A": 47.58773,
        "vT12A": 61.480682,
        "vT01": 53.158005,
        "vT02": 55.39967,
        "vT03": 48.341976,
        "vT04": 64.40726,
        "vT05": 61.5194,
        "vT06": 43.275482,
        "vT07": 84.02856,
        "vT08": 0,
        "vT09": 0,
        "vT10": 0,
        "vT11": 0,
        "vT12": 0,
        "y": 664.07715
      }
    ],
    "v48": 6357.05,
    "a0": 1642.2837,
    "a1": 6357.05,
    "a2": 6357.05,
    "a3": 954.47327,
    "vT01A": 132.97466,
    "vT02A": 114.761314,
    "vT03A": 144.12593,
    "vT04A": 125.53026,
    "vT05A": 270.1223,
    "vT06A": 107.20463,
    "vT07A": 188.4266,
    "vT08A": 182.25163,
    "vT09A": 124.83493,
    "vT10A": 122.90766,
    "vT11A": 161.53473,
    "vT12A": 141.57909,
    "vT01": 147.44078,
    "vT02": 145.23305,
    "vT03": 123.04047,
    "vT04": 152.18077,
    "vT05": 155.08392,
    "vT06": 108.22903,
    "vT07": 123.26528,
    "vT08": 0,
    "vT09": 0,
    "vT10": 0,
    "vT11": 0,
    "vT12": 0,
    "y": 1752.7427
  }]
```

aca ejemplo de lo que realice como primer nivel que es mercado
me faltaria realizar el reduce para sector y rubro
item viene siendo cada variable del array del primer nivel

```
let this.mercadoData= DATA;
  public calculateTotal(item: string) {
    return this.mercadoData.reduce((accum, curr) => accum + curr[`${item}`], 0);
  }
```

Si me pueden ayudar le agradeceria

Saludos

Comment: Buenas, no acabo de entender que es lo que quieres sumar. Te gustaria sumar todos los elementos de rubro entre si? te gustaria sumar solo un elemento en concreto dentro de rubro? como por ejemplo sumar los `v48` de los sectores? necesito mas informacion para resolver tu pregunta.

Comment: solo ir sumando por elemento por nivel primero acumulo v48 del luego el rubro, por ejemplo asi hice para sumar el primer nivel de array  pero el item lo paso como parametro con el nombre de la columna de una tabla ejem v48 this.mercadoData.reduce((accum, curr) => accum + curr[`${item}`], 0);